# How to scrape pod level info using prometheus kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-health-check

I am trying to scrape pod level info using prometheus kubernetes. Here is the config i am using:

```
 - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_servers:
    - 'https://kubernetes.default'
    role: pod
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: (.+):(?:\d+);(\d+)
    replacement: ${1}:${2}
    target_label: __address__
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

But i don't see any info on grafana. Do I need to make any changes in my apps?
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqjHS.png)

Comment: This article https://www.weave.works/blog/prometheus-and-kubernetes-monitoring-your-applications/ was very useful for me.

Answer (score 7):

With that configuration the first action asks that the pod be annotated with `prometheus.io/scrape=true`. Have you set that annotation on the pods in question?

Comment: Yes i have set the annotations. Is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: From the pod (app) perspective, apart from setting annotations, do i need to publish any data or metrics?

Comment: Your applications need to expose data in the Prometheus format over HTTP (typically via a client library). Prometheus can't extract data from nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware,

there is a configuration mistake here:
**__meta_kubernetes_pod_namespace** does not exist and should be **__meta_kubernetes_namespace**

Best regards,

Bart

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure that the data which your Grafana graphs use is actually present in Prometheus.

I assume you're using this default [Grafana dashboard](https://grafana.net/dashboards/747).

Your Grafana query might look like this:

```
sum (container_memory_working_set_bytes{pod_name=~"^$Pod$"}) / sum (machine_memory_bytes{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}) * 100
```

So you'd have to make sure that the `container_memory_working_set_bytes` metric is recorded and that it has a field `pod_name`.

In case the metric is not recorded you'd have to do some digging in the logs of prometheus to check whether it is able to crawl the API.

In case the metric is there but the labels are wrong you could either adjust the query in Grafana or add another `relabel_config` in Prometheus. See [official documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/).

Comment: I see that under http://x.x.x.x:9090/targets, kuberneted-pods, there is an error Get http://x.x.x.x:9100/metrics: dial tcp x.x.x.x:9100: getsockopt: connection refused. So its not even able to scrape data

Comment: Check the logs of your prometheus pod then and try to resolve possible errors. For me it was bad credentials as described here: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/374

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: As of now i am using cadvisor to get pod level info like memory usage and cpu usage. Also have implemented the app to expose some metrics which prometheus scrapes.

Comment: @nocturnal did you use annotations instead of labels?